# Intellij not using project-specific Maven settings.xml file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have "main" `settings.xml` file I use for the majority of my repos in my .m2 folder on my computer. However, I have 1 Java/Maven/IntelliJ project that has a custom settings.xml.

Instead of having to swap them out each time, I set the path to this "custom" settings.xml in my IntelliJ project and ticked the "Override" box, which to my knowledge, should pull this custom settings.xml file and NOT the one in my .m2 folder. But this is not working for some reason:
[image]

It keeps trying to use the `settings.xml` that is located in my `/.m2` folder directory and **NOT** the one in mmy `/git/` directory. Am I doing something wrong here???

Comment: Checkout this https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001530799-Custom-Maven-settings-are-ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166074). Please follow it for updates.